# get past day from difference 2 date

Tags: php

i want to get how many past day from difference 2 date.

PHP CODE:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2013-02-20');
$date2 = new DateTime('2013-02-22');
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
if (  $interval->days >= 0)
      echo "past day:" . $interval->days . " das ";
```

result is : 2, how to get -2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property `invert` of DateInterval specifies whether the interval is negative or not.

Thus:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2013-02-20');
$date2 = new DateTime('2013-02-22');
$interval = $date2->diff($date1);

if ($interval->days >= 0) {
      echo 'Past day: ', (($interval->invert ? -1 : 1) * $interval->days), ' days ';
}
```

Comment: @DoSparKot: Requires at least 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$date2->diff($date1);
```